# Direct .bat file to python virtual environment

Tags: batch-file, python-venv

I am trying to run a python script with a pyautogui library in it with windows task scheduler (.bat file).
This throws me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\autoupdate\script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

The script does work if I run it manually from PyCharm. Probably I need to direct BATCH file to a vinv with desired libreries.
Could you please tell me how to do that?

.bat file I use:

```
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\autoupdate\script.py"
exit
```

Comment: I would assume that the `pyautogui` module can only be imported when your user environment and / or current directory is relative. When you run as a scheduled task, it is most often run under a different user environment and with a different current directory. The information about your environment and the settings for your scheduled task therefore need to be added to your question by way of [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60743435/edit).

Comment: The vinv I used had a lot of libraries. Creating new one with pyautogui only in it solved the problem. (No edits to .bat and .py were made, except paths). Should I investigate further to get an answer to my question for community sake?

Comment: It seems like path to venv was the wrong one.